# получение значений из темы в андроиде

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема. делаю игру на андроид API19. есть несколько тем(можно динамически менять в игре). в теме есть R.attr.myColor(вообще любая ссылка)
который ссылается на цвет текста. Вопрос - как программно узнать это цвет, если текущая тема неизвестна заранее, или если даже известна, все равно решения не нашел для API19. в API21 есть способ. Пасиб..

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте один из этих методов:

```
/**
 * @param addressInRClass R.color.someColor or R.attr.someReferenceToColor
 * @return not id of recourse, but Color itself. I think so)
 */
public static int getColor(Context ctx, int addressInRClass) {
    int colorId;
    int[] attrs = new int[]{addressInRClass};
    TypedArray ta = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    colorId = ta.getColor(0, Color.RED);
    ta.recycle();

    return colorId;
}

public static int getAttrColor(Context context, int addressInRClass) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(addressInRClass, typedValue, true);
    Timber.d("typedValue.data: %s", typedValue.data);
    return typedValue.data;
}

@ColorRes
public static int getColorResId(Context context, int addressInRClass) {
    int colorId;
    int[] attrs = new int[]{addressInRClass};
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    colorId = ta.getResourceId(0, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
    ta.recycle();

    return colorId;
}
```